# Anylogic during GIS model run the massage: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: anylogic

i got a problem with GIS map update and routs findings. The massage i got

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Also the GIS map is not loading.

Kinly ask you to suggest what can be fixed with Anylogic and|or WIndows

Thank you in advance

Printscreen of the error:
[image]

Comment: Kindly add some more details how you get this error :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises when the server has a self-signed certificate. Please double-check that in your GIS map the Tile provider has been selected as AnyLogic and that the routes are also "Requested from OSM serve" and that the Routing server is chosen as "AnyLogic".

This might just be a temporary issue on AnyLogic side, if if persists please contact support.